# A good word for "quest" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, definiciones

The translation for Quest is "búsqueda" but it just does not work properly. In English we say "I'm on a quest for the holy grail" this is not quite the same as "I'm searching for the holy grail." So how do I get the seance of adventure implied in "quest" in Spanish. Can some one think of a better word.

Comment: A usual translation is "misión"

Comment: Maybe **en busca de** can work. It might imply a bit of action. For example the film "Raiders of the lost ark" is known as "En busca del arca perdida"

Comment: Misión y desafío traducen mejor a la magnifica palabra `quest`!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: in Spanish the closest word etymologically speaking is [cuestación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bb1kPkk): _Petición o demanda de limosnas para un objeto piadoso o benéfico._ It comes from the same latin word as "[quest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quest)": Middle English, from Anglo-French _queste_, Vulgar Latin _quaesta_, from Latin, feminine of _quaestus_, past participle of _quaerere_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "misión" is pretty common, here are some example websites in Spanish using it in a game context:
http://es.wowhead.com/faction=942/expedicion-cenarion#quests
http://www.eliteguias.com/guias/t/tes5s/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-misiones-de-los-companeros.php

Comment: Grasias la palabra "misión" funsiona mejor.

Comment: There are some movies with the word *Quest* translated to «Búsqueda». http://tinyurl.com/89p8orj

Comment: "desafío" is another option

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a word in Spanish with the same sense of adventure. Nonetheless, a "[quest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quest)" also means

> a long and difficult effort to find or do something.

A word in Spanish with a similar meaning is **empresa**:

> **[empresa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EsuT8Fg)**
>
> 1. f. Acción o tarea que entraña dificultad y cuya ejecución requiere decisión y esfuerzo.

In almost most of the cases, the word *empresa* means "company", "business", "enterprise". But it can also reflect a long, difficult task in general. An example taken from *Don Quixote*:

> Por una parte, me acosa y fatiga el deseo de ver a mi señora; por otra, me incita y llama la prometida fe, y la gloria que he de alcanzar en esta empresa.
>
> *On the one hand the desire to see my lady pursues and harasses me, on the other my solemn promise and the glory I shall win in this enterprise urge and call me.*

The translator chose "enterprise" for the translation, but maybe nowadays it could have been "quest" as well.

Answer (score -1):

Quest. Como en la hermosa canción "The man of La Mancha", referida a Don Quijote, que tiene la preciosa expresión en inglés:

> This is my quest
>    To follow that star
>    No matter how hopeless
>    No matter how far

Lo traduciría como mi **anhelo**, mi sueño, mi ideal, mi sed, mi norte, mi causa. La canción de Paloma San Basilio usa la palabra **afán**, en el sentido de misión, propósito.

Comment: Bienvenido al foro. La propuesta que haces podría servir para otros casos, como la canción cuya letra copias; pero no veo cómo sirve para el ejemplo que se planteaba en la pregunta.